# No resizes the height of the frame

Tags: javascript, iframe, iframe-resizer

I have a site A which contains a frame with the content of the site B and is not automatically resizes , and try changing the value of heightCalculationMethod and always gives me the same size , the log always shows me the following :

> 1.[iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] Added missing iframe ID: iFrameResizer0 ()
>
> 2.[iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] IFrame scrolling disabled for iFrameResizer0
>
> 3.[iFrameSizer][Host page: iFrameResizer0] [init] Sending msg to iframe[iFrameResizer0] (iFrameResizer0:8:false:true:32:true:true:null:lowestElement:null:null:0:false:parent:scroll) targetOrigin: *

only that.

Resume

**Site A:**
**Domain:** a.com
**Library:**
iframeResizer.js and
iframeResizer.contentWindow.js

**js :**

```
iFrameResize ({
    log : true,
    heightCalculationMethod : ' lowestElement '
    checkOrigin : false
});
```

**html:**

```
   <iframe ng-src="{{url}}" width="100" frameborder="0"     scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

where url is a variable that contains the url of the site B

**Site B:**
**Domain:** b.com
**Library :** 
    iframeResizer.contentWindow.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the second JS file into you iFrame.

Comment: Hi David, which is the second file? iframeResizer.contentWindow.js? in both sites (a.com and b.com) i have this file. If both sites are in the same domain the resizer works, but, if them are in different domains the resizer not work. Which is the problem?

Comment: Sorry David , you were right , the other file had not been properly loaded with bower , and I realized the error. Thanks for your help